# Set different "Associated View" view for intersect entity in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have a 'manual N:N' relationship configured between the opportunity and account entities, with an OpportunityAccount entity in the middle.  There is a subgrid on both the opportunity and account entities displaying the intersect OpportunityAccount entity, which works very well.

The issue is that the 'associated view' button on each subgrid displays the 'OpportunityAccount associated view' regardless of which entity it is being clicked from, and there is a requirement that the views be different, showing opportunity details when clicked from the account, and vice versa.  Essentially, I'm looking to replicate the default behavior of a standard CRM N:N relationship, but with the custom intersect entity instead of the internal one that CRM creates and maintains using the 'add N:N' functionality.

Is this possible?  I've looked at the areas.aspx page that loads when the 'associated records' button is clicked and don't see any URL parameters I can pass to choose a particular view, or any opportunity to inject JS to somehow select the right view based on context.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify a different associated view. You can of course include fields from both the Account and Opportunity sides so that they are visible in either case. But this means half of them are redundant half of the time.

Rather than the associated view, perhaps you could add a subgrid to Account form and Opportunity form, and in each case select a specific view of your custom intersect entity that you have created to show the fields you need.